# In LyX, tikz-cd appears inline. How to make it display as in Display Formula?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, tikz-cd, inline

I am typing an article in LyX. I use ERT to input tikz-cd. The diagram is faithfully shown in the output, but always inline. I would like to make it display, precisely like a Display Formula in LyX, so that the diagram's alignment is Center but the alignment of the rest of the paragraph remains Justified. How could I achieve that?

I have tried to put the ERT box containing tikz-cd into a Display Formula box by selecting the ERT box and pressing Ctrl+Shift+M, but that just removes the ERT from the tikz-cd code leaving it as plain text.

I have also tried to save the diagram in a separate document and to insert it using Insert -> File -> Child Document, and selecting Input for the Include Type, but again I get the diagram inline.

Note that I can make the diagram's alignment Center by putting it into a separate paragraph and selecting Center alignment for the paragraph, but that is not what I am looking for because the diagram is a part of the sentence so I don't want to rip it out, I just want to display it.

Here is an example of the issue.

[image: lyx code]
[image: pdf output]

Regardless of the outcome, thank you for your good will!

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Please give a minimal example .lyx file. https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty I haven't found an option to upload a file, so I have uploaded screenshots, instead. I hope that they suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue by simple typing \[ and \], respectively, before and after the tikz-cd code within the ERT box. Now it seems like an obvious thing to try in the first place, but last night I was too busy trying to find a LyX way to display the diagram written within the ERT box that it didn't occur to me to display it from within the ERT box.

I apologize for posting the question too soon.